# How do I use array_udiff() correctly?

Tags: php, arrays, diff

I have two multidimensional arrays that both look something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array (
         'id' => 3,
         'other' => 'some string',
         'timestamp' => 2000-01-01 00:00:00
    ),

    [1] => Array (
         'id' => 6,
         'other' => 'another string',
         'timestamp' => 1835-01-01 00:00:00
    )
)
```

I'm trying to find a way to figure out which elements show up in one array (`$b`), but not the other (`$a`) and if there are any elements with changed values. If `$a` is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array (
         'id' => 3,
         'other' => 'some string',
         'timestamp' => 2000-01-01 00:00:00
    )
)
```

and `$b` is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array (
         'id' => 3,
         'other' => 'some string',
         'timestamp' => 2000-01-01 12:12:12
    ),

    [1] => Array (
         'id' => 4,
         'other' => 'some string',
         'timestamp' => 1900-01-01 01:12:23
    )
)
```

Then the function should return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array (
         'id' => 3,
         'other' => 'some string',
         'timestamp' => 2000-01-01 12:12:12
    ),

    [1] => Array (
         'id' => 4,
         'other' => 'some string',
         'timestamp' => 1900-01-01 01:12:23
    )
)
```

because the element with `id = 3` has been changed (the `timestamp` field) and the element with `id = 4` is new and doesn't appear in the other array.

I've been trying to do this with `array_udiff`, but I still don't know how it works (it seems to sort both arrays first, but then how does it do comparison?). Is `array_udiff` the proper method or should I write a custom function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `array_udiff` and define your own comparison callback. I assume that both arrays has exactly the same structure.

You can define your own callback function as follow:

```
int comparison(Array $a, Array $b){
    if ($a['id']==$b['id'] && $a['other']==$b['other'] && $a['timestamp']==$b['timestamp']){
        return 0
    }else{
        return -1
    }
}
```

The callback function must return a negative integer if first argument is less than the second; a positive number if it's bigger; or 0 if it's equal. Then, you can return any number different to 0 to indicate that the arguments are different and 0 if they are the equal.

Finally, you should call `array_udiff`as follow:

```
array_udiff($a, $b, 'comparison')
```

And you will get a list of the elements of `$a` which are not, or are different in `$b`.

Note that if you want to compare 2 array when one of then has more elements than the other, you should pass as first argument the array with the new elements.

Comment: Doesn't the callback function have to return all of `0`, `1` and `-1`?

Comment: @MaxMackie The callback funtion must return a negative number, 0 or a positive number if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second. But for your porpose you only need to return if the arguments are equal (return 0) or different (return a positive or negative number).

Comment: but how are -1, 0, and 1 handled/interpreted?

1 is include, 0 and -1 are exclude?

Comment: If `array_udiff` Interprets 0/1 as a binary comparison (i.e. 0 => equal, not 0 => different), I do not see the utility of the callback function of returning possitive / negative values, as they are in both cases included in the final array. Someone to point me out?

Comment: @andcl My understanding is that it sorts the array first, which is why it wants the -1, 0, 1.

Answer (score 0):

The return for array_udiff function "data_compare_func" is some function that you define but it must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero so its probably not the right function for your needs. A custom function like this should give you what you need:

```
// this function loops through both arrays to find a match in the other array
// it will skip entry comparisons when it goes through $arr2 because you already did it the first time
function find_diff($arr1, $arr2) {
    $ret = array();

    // we need to do two loops to find missing entries from both arrays
    $ret = do_loop($arr1, $arr2, $ret, true);
    $ret = do_loop($arr2, $arr1, $ret, false);
    return $ret;
}

// this function does the looping though $arr1 to compare it to entries in $arr2
// you can skip entry comparison if $compare_entries is false
function do_loop($arr1, $arr2, $ret, $compare_entries = true) {
    //look through all of $arr1 for same element in $arr2 based on $id
    for ($i=0;$i<count($arr1);$i++) {
        $id = $arr1[$i]['id'];
        $found = false;

        for ($j=0;$j<count($arr2);$j++) {
            // id match found
            if ($id == $arr2[$j]['id']) {
                $found = true;
                // only compare entries if you need to
                if ($compare_entries) {
                    //check if other field is different
                    if (strcmp($arr1[$i]['other'],$arr2[$j]['other']) != 0) {
                        $ret = add_to_ret($arr1[$i], $ret);
                        break;
                    }
                    //check if timestamp field is different
                    if (strcmp($arr1[$i]['timestamp'],$arr2[$j]['timestamp']) != 0) {
                        $ret = add_to_ret($arr1[$i], $ret);
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // entry from $arr1[$i] was not found in $arr2
        if (!$found) {
            $ret = add_to_ret($arr1[$i], $ret);
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}


//this function only adds the new entry to $ret if it's ID isn't already in $ret
function add_to_ret($entry, $ret) {

    $id = $entry['id'];

    for ($i=0;$i<count($ret);$i++) {
        if ($id == $ret[$i]['id']) {
            //skip adding, its already in there
            return $ret;
        }
    }
    //add it in
    $ret[] = $entry;
    return $ret;
}
```