# Using array_udiff with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to using array_udiff with codeigniter however i'm getting this error for the callback paramter:

```
Message:  Undefined property: Basic_model::$udiffCompare
```

Here is the part of the controller

```
$this->load->model('basic_model');
$arrdiff = array_udiff($array1, $array2, $this->basic_model->udiffCompare);
```

and the callback method in the Basic_model

```
public function udiffCompare($a, $b)
    {
        return $a['id'] - $b['id'];
    }
```

How can I make it look in the correct model?

Answer (score 0):

You no need a call back on `array_udiff`

```
$arrdiff = array_udiff($array1, $array2, "callback_myfunction");
```

In same controller add this

```
public function myfunction($a,$b)
{

    if ($a===$b)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return ($a>$b)?1:-1;
     }
}
```

[image]

[`array_udiff` in W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_udiff.asp) and [How do I use array_udiff() correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341520/how-do-i-use-array-udiff-correctly)

Comment: That doesn't work. I dont think you can call methods like that in codeigniter. This is the error: Message:  array_udiff() expects parameter 3 to be a valid callback, function 'myfunction' not found or invalid function name

Comment: use `callback_funcion_name`

Comment: @user2570937 check now. Edited

Comment: still doesn't work. Message:  array_udiff() expects parameter 3 to be a valid callback, function 'callback_myfunction' not found or invalid function name

Comment: @user2570937 If this help please **[Mark it as ACCEPT**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Hence [**VOTE UP** will lead my TAG count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)